# MBProgressHud and issues with the constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, mbprogresshud

I am trying to show a toast using the MBProgressHud and here's the code,

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:view animated:YES];
[hud setMode:MBProgressHUDModeText];
[hud setLabelText:toastText];
hud.labelText.accessibilityLabel = toastText;
hud.yOffset = offset;
[hud hide:YES afterDelay:1.5f];
```

The `yoffset` can be used to push the toast down. Can this have constraints ? Does MBProgressHUD come with layout constraints. I need to show this just above the of the screen and it should work for all resolutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately used self.view.frame/2 - 100 which works fine for most the screen resolutions the project work on supports.

Answer (score 0):

[image]how did you set the`offset`,in the api doc of MBProgressHUD,the owner show how to set the hud in the view's bottom.

```
CGPoint point = CGPointMake(0.f, MBProgressMaxOffset), then set it to offset.
```

Comment: This is in the new version. The old version doesn't have the offset value property. It just has the xoffset and yoffset properties

Comment: if you don't need to change many code, i suggest you update your `MBProgressHUD` version, the newest version solved some mistake.

Comment: can you tell me the version of your `MBProgressHUD`.

Comment: It has a lot of dependencies in my project. Cannot just change. I am in 0.9